# Can't install code as package

Tags: package, doom, polymode

I've recently started to look into the [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) framework and noticed there is no available major-mode for editing .razor files, which are essentially a mix of C# and HTML. I then started creating a [simple package](https://github.com/aserranoni/blazor-mode/blazor-mode.el) using polymode for this purpose. I'm trying to follow [these directions](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MakingPackages)

The issue I'm having is that I can't install my code as package. On the other hand, if I paste the definitions into my config file everything works as expected.

Does anyone have a clue of what my problem may be?

**MORE INFO**:

- EMACS VERSION: GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 3, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-06-07
- Doom core     v3.0.0-dev       HEAD -> master 33c5f3721 2022-07-09 21:10:40 +0200
- Doom modules  v22.07.0-dev     HEAD -> master 33c5f3721 2022-07-09 21:10:40 +0200
- I'm trying to install the package using the following function call: `(package! blazor-mode :recipe (:local-repo "~/blazor-mode"))`

Comment: Did you used the command ```doom sync``` from terminal to install? what errors do you have?

Comment: Yes, I've used doom sync (also tried with the -u flag, which updates the packages as well). I can see it interacts with my files (both local and from my github repo) and there are no errors. However, when I open up a .razor file, the syntax highlighting doesn't work and the blazor-mode function is not there. The doom doctor command also doesn't appear to spot any problems with my code

Comment: Did you added a simple line ```(use-package blazor-mode)``` to your ```~/.doom.d/config``` file?

Answer (score 1):

`package!` can install a package from a local folder:

```lisp
(package! package-name :recipe
  (:local-repo "~/path/to/code"))
```

Regardless, `web-mode` already supports `.razor` files! Have you tried enabling the `web` module?

If the web module doesn't cover razor files, try this snippet to let web-mode handle `.razor` files:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'web-mode-engines-alist '("razor" . "\\.razor\\'"))
```